# AVAssetWriter with non-constant frame rates

Tags: ios, avassetwriter

I'm trying to export a series of JPG images into a H264 movie (ideally it would be a motion JPEG movie, but unfortunately out `AVAssetWriter` does not support this codec).

The images come with a surveillance camera with VFR (variable frame rate), hence I compute the `CMTime` based on the time they have been captured, which – due to the way the VFR camera works – results in a non-constant frame rate.

When I do this though, the `AVAssetWriter` always fails to render the movie:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16364), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x604000245a90 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16364 "(null)"}}`

When I change the `CMTime` instances to be e.g. `CMMakeTime( frameIndex * 150, 600 )` it works.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-16364 is the code for invalid time code. It turned out I computed a wrong `CMTime` for the last image I wrote, which made the time going *backwards*. `AVAssetWriter` does not like that -- and rightly so.

Thanks to bford in the [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92020) who helped me solve this problem.

Comment: It'd be better if Apple actually documented these error codes instead of having to rely on bford.